# Add users to Google Groups using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm having a dedicated google group on my site. On other page of the site I'm using script to manage spreadsheet. I also manage "users", as name, nickname and email to use in the spreadsheet (only as string)

Is there a way to add the user mail address I add to my spreadsheet also as member of the group I having ???

I found some Google groups api, but noting about setting, just getting values...

Answer (score -1):

It's in the Provisioning API which I'm currently writing a Google Script library for and it should be ready in the next few weeks. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#adding_a_member_to_a_group

Check out: http://GoogleScriptExamples.com/custom-methods

Comment: as i'm not at all familiar to "protocol", what should I do with `POST https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/group/2.0/domain/groupId/member` ?? where and how to write it ? directly in the G.A.Script ?