# How to add people to google groups programmatically using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-groups

```
  var form = FormApp.openById('1IErsge8yafg0UOltvhecAMhRd5Yh1VXJdhkI');
  var groupID = "mygroup@googlegroups.com";

  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    var email = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
    Logger.log(email);
    var newMember = {email: email, role: "MEMBER"};
    AdminDirectory.Members.insert(newMember, groupID);
  }

}
```

This is the code I've written and I'm getting an error
[image]

After some research I found out that the error is because I don't have a G Suite subscription.

However, I am not able to find anything about how achieve the same task without a G Suite subscription. Can anyone please help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need the id. You can make a test request [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list) and see the id. It looks like this: `22y111xx3f8ri5j` That worked for me, just tested it.

Comment: Please add more details. Are you a Google Workspace Admin? Are you able to list the groups in your domain? P.S. Error messages should be added as text, not as images. P.S.S. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/21253849/1595451

Comment: In addition, you have an example in the official documentation: [Add group member](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_group_member)

Comment: @Rubén I am not a Google workspace admin. I'm quite new to stack overflow and I didn't know we were supposed to add error as text. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Thanks for your reply abhi. Please consider to [edit] the question to replace the error image by the error text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you aren't Google Workspace Admin, please checkout [the Jay Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262115/1595451) to [Google Groups API add Member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21253849/1595451). Tl;Dr: `AdminDirectory` can be used only by Google Workspace Admins.

You might try to use the [Groups Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups) to get information about a Google Group but it hasn't a method to add users to a group, so your only options are to add the users manually or to use web-browser automation tool.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory

Related

- [Add users to Google Groups using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10444919/1595451)
- [Google Admin SDK error Resource Not Found: domain when trying to list existing users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27175867/1595451)
- [Issue adding members to @googlegroups.com with Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46251044/1595451)